# Is this a good / secure way to set server side cookies from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, reactjs

I am working with a single app application framework called [reactjs](https://facebook.github.io/react/), the issue I encountered is setting httpOnly cookies, as they can not be set / read from a client side I needed to figure out a way how to use express for this.

One idea I came up with is to make a post request to a route like `/cookie:data` where data is value of token that needs to be stored in a cookie, so:

```
app.post('/cookie:data', function(req, res) {
  // Set cookie here
  res.send(200)
})
```

Issue I am hesitant about is that token contains unique user identifier that is used to secure api, and I am not sure if I am or am not exposing this by setting up a cookie this way.

Alternatively instead of using `:data` it would be beneficial to figure out how I can grab data (json object) from the post request

**EDIT:**
One issue I can think of is that anyone can post to this route and set different cookies? what would be a way of securing it?

**EDIT 2:**
This is the express setup I use to proxy api calls (only relevant for clarifying comments)

```
  app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
    let url = config.API_HOST + req.url
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)
  })
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to set non-httpOnly cookies? In terms of safety I don't see how that would be more insecure than being able to set whatever cookie value through a server-side API. Also, the unique user identifier will be exposed one way or the other anyway, so using HTTPS seems like a mandatory requirement.

Comment: @robertklep the idea here is to figure out a viable way to set httpOnly cookies, non httpOnly ones are not an option for me I'm afraid due to they nature of being able to access them via js. HTTPS is on as well with cookies being secured.

Comment: Where exactly is the data that you want to store in the cookie coming from? I assume it's not coming from your own server? If your FE is calling a third-party API, wouldn't it be an idea to proxy requests to that API through your own server? For a serious attacker, not being able to read cookie contents might not be a barrier if they can control which cookies are being set anyhow (by calling `/cookie:data`).

Comment: @robertklep already using that to proxy '/api' to third party api url (see edit 2), however was not able to figure out a way to set a cookie on a successful response as I am using (.then and .catch) on the client side.

Comment: Can't you check for the particular API endpoints that are used for (I assume) authentication, and set a cookie from the `/api` handler if the authentication was successful?

Comment: @robertklep Thats what I was trying to figure out before coming up with a `/cookie` api approach, could you provide an example please? Assume that I am posting to a route like `/api/users` in order to (indeed) authenticate a user. This route returns a token that needs to be set as a value in cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that you want to proxy all requests starting with `/api` to a third-party, except `/api/users`, which you want to perform 'manually' because it returns a token you need:

```
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
  let url        = config.API_HOST + req.url;
  let apiRequest = request.post(url, function(err, response, body) {
    // Responses are just examples, you should tailor them to your situation
    if (err) {
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    } else if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
      return res.sendStatus(response.statusCode);
    } else {
      res.cookie('token', body).send('OK');
    }
  });
  req.pipe(apiRequest);
})

app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
  let url = config.API_HOST + req.url
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the job. However did have to fiddle around with a bodyParser a bit.

Comment: One issue I found is that using it this way I am no longer able to use `.then` and `.catch` hooks on the client side, is there a way to still keep those functional (I assumed sending status 500) would've mean that `.catch` is triggered

Comment: Which API are you using client-side?

Comment: And in terms of 3rd party service, it's our backend teams one, that I can't expose

Comment: It seems that body passed to the api/sessions express post is undefined and placing it under body parser causes call to time out.

Comment: I don't know how you're passing the data to your own server, that's why I made some assumptions. Timeouts on body parser sound like you may not be using it properly.

Comment: Thinking about it it is not technically my own server, it is hosted separately, and front-end application uses api that is connected to the server (i.e. on my side there are no database setups, token generations or checks etc..)

Body parser seems to be working fine, my initial proxy is placed above it, if I place it below its declaration, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See my edit, you should be able to pipe to `request.post()` as well.